# Flexbox item does not adjust to image height/is slightly larger

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I am trying to fit images inside flexbox items and want the outer div to adjust to the height of the image height.
But somehow, the outer div is slightly heigher than the image and I don't know what is causing that.

My HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
    </div>
    <div class="item">

    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
    width: 50%;
}
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And the result:

[image]
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0ewm6t3z/35/)

The images should touch at the edges but instead there's a gap. I already tried to set the margin and padding to 0 without success.

It would be great if someone could explain what is causing that.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add `vertical-align: bottom` to the images: https://jsfiddle.net/hz36o7r0/1/

Comment: That does the trick. But could you explain why there's a gap?

Comment: It's explained in my answer in the duplicate. If you're still unclear after reading it, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Sorry for the duplicate. Didn't find the duplicated question.

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

can try to add that css:

```
.item {
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

that can solve your problem